# In jQuery how to avoid repeated codes like this for toggle?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Currently using the following *jquery* code to **toggle** open/close on-clicking the category and to display the subcategory beneath. I am 100% sure there's better way than this but need a pointer please. Using this for mobile version display port.

```
    $(function () {
    $('#panel1').click(function () {    $('#panelx1').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel2').click(function () {    $('#panelx2').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel3').click(function () {    $('#panelx3').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel4').click(function () {    $('#panelx4').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel5').click(function () {    $('#panelx5').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel6').click(function () {    $('#panelx6').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel7').click(function () {    $('#panelx7').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel8').click(function () {    $('#panelx8').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel9').click(function () {    $('#panelx9').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel10').click(function () {    $('#panelx10').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel11').click(function () {    $('#panelx11').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel12').click(function () {    $('#panelx12').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel13').click(function () {    $('#panelx13').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel14').click(function () {    $('#panelx14').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel15').click(function () {    $('#panelx15').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel16').click(function () {    $('#panelx16').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel17').click(function () {    $('#panelx17').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel18').click(function () {    $('#panelx18').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel19').click(function () {    $('#panelx19').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel20').click(function () {    $('#panelx20').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel21').click(function () {    $('#panelx21').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel22').click(function () {    $('#panelx22').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel23').click(function () {    $('#panelx23').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
    $('#panel24').click(function () {    $('#panelx24').addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" ); });
})
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Just to be clear, this application does not uses bootstrap so I can't use data-toggle.

Application is in PHP and every new categories are added, it increases the ID numbers. I wish there was a way I could just type type php string which would pull PHP variable value from below but not sure now to do with jquery.

Comment: javascript has loops, similar to the concept of loops in php. read about the language, it should help you to use it for your benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dynamic classes, use a single class (one for the clickable panel, one for the category) and when the nth panel is clicked, change the nth category. Eg, with `panel` and `category` classes:

```
const panels = $('.panel');
const categories = $('.category');
panels.each((i, panel) => {
  $(panel).on('click', () => {
    categories.eq(i).addClass('active-category').toggle( "slow" );
  });
});
```